# Show that $(a,b)=1$ and $c\mid a$ implies $(c,b)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a proof in mind:

Since $c\mid a$, there exist q such that $a = c q$.

Let $d\mid c$ and $d\mid b$, this then implies $d|(b+cq)$ and $d\mid (b-cq)$, which then implies $d\mid (b+a)$ and $d\mid (b-a)$.

And in turn, these imply $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$. Since $(a,b)=1$, we have $d = 1$.

Therefore, $(b,c)=1$.

Is this a good/legit proof?

Comment: This is a one(or two atmost) line proof if you use Bezouts Identity.

Comment: I just realised a fault in my proof (thanks to a colleague): $d|(b+a)$ and $d|(b-a)$ doesn't imply $d|a$ and $d|b$ directly.

Answer (score 2):

Or more succinctly, $d|(c,\,b)\implies d|c\land d|b\stackrel{c|a}{\implies}d|a\land d|b\stackrel{(a,\,b=1)}{\implies}d|1$, so $(c,\,b)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted in comments, your proof is flawed.  I sure didn't catch it.

An alternate strategy is to use the fact that, since $(a,b)=1$, we can choose integers $x,y$ such that $$ax+by=1$$  Since we know that $a=cq$ as you say, this becomes $$c(qx)+by=1$$ from which we can conclude that $(b,c)=1$.

Comment: No, the OP's proof is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be the equivalent as being told to buy a pack of gum from the local store, and solving that by going to the factory, buying a case of gum, taking the case of gum to the local store and selling it to the store but taking one package as commission, and then going home with your pack of gum.

Yes, your proof is legitimate.

But $\gcd(b,c)|c$ and $c|a$ so $\gcd(b,c)|a$ and $\gcd(b,c)|b$ so $\gcd(b,c)$ is a common divisor of $a,b$.  So $\gcd(b,c) \le \gcd(a,b)=1$.  So $\gcd(b,c) = 1$.

Comment: No, the OP's proof is not correct.

Comment: Yeah.... you are right.